# MS SQL On Using WHERE EXISTS and WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using EXISTS AND NOT EXISTS IN THE same query, but not getting any results. I'm looking for results where there is a particular position and sub position, but want to exclude items where that particular position exists, but the subposition is null. I'm a newbie, so I'm probably missing something here.  Here is my query:

```
    SELECT a.*
    FROM dbo.table AS a
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Distinct b.EventID
                FROM dbo.table AS b
                WHERE b.EventID = a.EventID
                AND b.Position = 'ABC' 
                AND b.SubPosition = 'DEF') 

    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Distinct b.EventID
                FROM  dbo.table AS b
                WHERE b.EventID = a.EventID
                AND  b.Position = 'ABC'
                AND  b.SubPosition IS NULL)
```

Thx.

Comment: Based on your description, the queries look reasonable, except you should replace `select distinct b.eventId` with something simpler such as `select 1`.  Perhaps you could edit the question with sample data and the results that you want to get.

Comment: You definitely don't need the DISTINCT clause, just because the EXISTS clause is just looking for the existence of at least one record anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXCEPT` is an alternative to `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` in the same query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Test T
  WHERE T.EventId IN
   (
     SELECT EventId FROM Test T WHERE T.Position = 'ABC' AND T.SubPosition = 'DEF'
     EXCEPT
     SELECT EventId FROM Test T WHERE T.Position = 'ABC' AND T.SubPosition IS NULL
   )
```

`EXCEPT` will yield distinct rows.

Comment: With some tweaking, this is the query that finally worked. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First, your English language description is unclear, and does not match the SQL.  If you are looking
".. for results where there is a particular position and sub position, ..."

Then you would simply write

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table a
Where Position = 'ABC' 
   AND SubPosition = 'DEF'
```

and obviously, none of those rows will have a null subposition ...

So I assume you meant to write: 
"*looking for results of all rows for those eventIds where there is a row for that eventId with a particular position and sub position, ...."*

then, from within that resultset you wish to exclude those rows with null SubPosition?
If that is accurate, then try this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table a
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.table 
     WHERE EventID = a.EventID
        AND Position = 'ABC' 
        AND SubPosition = 'DEF') 
   AND SubPosition IS NULL
```

Another way to write this is with `IN` operator (in which case the sub-query is not correlated, so you don't need any aliases):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table
WHERE EventID In 
    (SELECT EventID 
     FROM dbo.table 
     WHERE Position = 'ABC' 
        AND SubPosition = 'DEF') 
  AND SubPosition IS NULL
```

EDIT:
   After your comment, I am guessing what you meant was actually:
"*looking for results of all rows for those eventIds where there exists a row for that eventId with a particular position and sub position, but there does NOT EXIST any row with that position and a null subposition .*"  This is different from eliminating rows with Null subposition from the output!  THis eliminates rows for EventIds where there is any row in the table with a null subposition.  Is this what you want? If so,

Then try this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table a
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.table 
     WHERE EventID = a.EventID
        AND Position = 'ABC' 
        AND SubPosition = 'DEF') 
   AND Not EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.table 
     WHERE EventID = a.EventID
        AND Position = 'ABC' 
        AND SubPosition IS NULL)
```

ok,  try these queries and tell me what you get

```
     SELECT * FROM dbo.table 
     WHERE EventID = 2
        AND Position = 'ABC' 
        AND SubPosition = 'DEF' -- should return one row
```

and...

```
     SELECT * FROM dbo.table 
     WHERE EventID = 2
        AND Position = 'ABC' 
        AND SubPosition IS NULL -- should return NO rows
```

If this is true, then the main query should also return the one row with EventId = 2

FURTHUR EDIT:

Execute this to create test table with test data and execute query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST](
[EventId] [int] NULL,
[Pos] [char](3) NULL,
[subPos] [char](3) NULL
)

Insert Test(EventId, Pos, SubPos) Values (1, 'ABC', 'DEF')
Insert Test(EventId, Pos, SubPos) Values (1, 'ABC', null)
Insert Test(EventId, Pos, SubPos) Values (2, 'ABC', 'DEF')
Insert Test(EventId, Pos, SubPos) Values (3, 'ABC', 'DEF')
Insert Test(EventId, Pos, SubPos) Values (3, 'ABC', null)

SELECT * FROM dbo.test a
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.test 
     WHERE EventID = a.EventID
       AND Pos = 'ABC' 
       AND SubPos = 'DEF') 
  AND Not EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.test 
     WHERE EventID = a.EventID
       AND Pos = 'ABC' 
       AND SubPos IS NULL)
```

BTW,  you don't need an alias for a table or resultset unless you need to reference that table/resultset from outside that part of the query.  The only place in your query where that is the case is for the main table, which needs to be referenced from the two correlated sub-queries. 
The correleated subqueries are not referenced by anything.

Comment: You are correct. That is what I want, but I just tried the query and it isn't returning what I need. It's returning all the position types, not just 'ABC'.

Comment: Sorry, just tried it and doesn't work. Returns nothing.

Comment: Does this help -I have 1, ABC, DEF; 1, ABC, NULL; 2, ABC, DEF; 3, ABC, DEF; 3, ABC, NULL. I just want result 2 returned. Thx

Comment: It should work.. The first subquery is true for EventId = 2, there DOES exist a row with 2, ABC, DEF.   and the second subquery is also true, there does NOT exist a row with 2, ABC, Null.  So the query should return that single row...

Comment: Tried your last two simple queries and of course they work. But I don't know the EventID beforehand if I want to run a correct query. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: If the two sample queries do as they should then the main query should return the one row you want. If it isn't, then you are typing it wrong, or the data is not as you describe it.  I just recreated it with a test table and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the example data of

```
1, ABC, DEF
2, ABC, NULL
3, ABC, IFG
```

The first subquery will match only 1, so the EXISTS returns true.

The second subquery will match 1 and 3, so the NOT EXISTS returns false.

so the query reduces to: SELECT * FROM dbo.table WHERE 1 AND 0, which returns no records.

I think that you could do SELECT * from dbo.table WHERE Position = 'ABC' AND SubPosition = 'DEF' to get the records you want, which is that Position is ABC and SubPosition is DEF.  The whole "is not null" part makes no sense if you want a specific SubPosition as well, so maybe the question needs to be re-thought...?

EDIT after reading all the comments:

Ah, now I get what you want (maybe):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table a 
WHERE a.Position = 'ABC' AND 
     a.SubPosition='DEF' AND 
     NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table 
                  WHERE a.EventID = EventID AND 
                        a.Position = Position AND 
                        SubPosition = NULL)
```

Comment: No, I have 1, ABC, DEF; 1, ABC, NULL; 2, ABC, DEF; 3, ABC, DEF; 3, ABC, NULL. I just want result 2 returned.